# Will a procedure be considered as a predicate, <p> , when the special form cond is missing the key word else?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I accidentally forgot to put the `else` in the following `cond` expression, and something strange occurred.

```
(define (abs x)
  (cond ((< x 0) x)
        ((= x 0) 0)
        (+ 1 2 1001)
        ))

> (abs 1)
1001
>
```

the result of `(abs 1)` is not the result of `(+ 1 2 1001)`，which is 1004, but the last element of the arguments of the expression `(+ 1 2 1001)`.

the `cond` form is

```
(cond (<p1>,<e1>)
      (<p2>,<e2>)
      (<p3>,<e3>)
      ...
      (<pn>,<en>))
```

there is no predicate in the expression `(+ 1 2 1001)`, so I wonder if the procedure `+` has been considered as predicate, and if it always evaluates as true, selecting the last element to return. Is that how it works???

Comment: Maybe you will interesting "cond.rkt"

Comment: it's not a predicate there in the cond's clauses, it's a Boolean. you get a Boolean  by calling a predicate, or it just might already be  there, like `(< x 0)` or  `+` . `cond` is actually different than what you show, it's `(cond (<p1> <e11> ...) ...)` (plus the else clause).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sequencing**: [`begin`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/begin.html) form in Racket allows you to sequence multiple expressions. It evaluates each expression from left to right and the final result is the last expression.

**Syntax**: The syntax for [`cond`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html) shows that multiple expressions can be sequenced in the rhs of a clause without a `begin`. Such a thing is called an *implicit begin*.

**Semantics**: According to the documentation, `cond` evaluates the rhs of a clause if the lhs is anything but `#f`. Therefore `+` in the position of the test-expression evaluates the rhs of the clause.

**Style**: By convention, using square brackets in a few key places makes Racket code even more readable. The *clause* of a cond is one of these places.

The following snippet is equivalent to your snippet:

```
#lang racket

(define (abs x)
  (cond [(< x 0) x]
        [(= x 0) 0]
        [+ (begin 1
                  2
                  1001)]))
(abs 1) 
; => 1001
```

Answer (score 4):

[`cond`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=cond#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29) works like this:

```
(cond (test-expr then-body) 
      (test-expr2 then-body2)
      (else then-body3))
```

The test-exprs are tested one by one, and the first test-expr that returns a non-false value causes its corresponding then-body to be executed. The last value in the executed then-body is the value of the whole cond.

In Scheme, anything not `#f` is considered true. Therefore, `+` is considered true. In your `cond`, `+` acts like an `else` because it is always true. In fact, your code could be written like this without any change in behavior:

```
(define (abs x)
  (cond ((< x 0) x)
        ((= x 0) 0)
        (else 1 2 1001)))
```

In your original code, the first test-expr that returns a non-false value is `+`. Since `1001` is the last value of the executed then-body, `1001` is the value of the whole `cond`. That's why you got `1001`.

Answer (score 3):

`cond` is a way to do if-elseif*-else in lisp and getting a flatter structure than with nesting of `if`.  Since `cond` is derived form you could write your conditional in terms of `if`. Your procedure would become:

```
(define (abs x)
  (if (< x 0) 
      x
      (if (= x 0) 
          0
          (if +
              (begin
                1 
                2 
                1001)))))
```

The last `if` checks if `+` is truthy. **Every** expression not evaluating to `#f` is truthy so all procedures are truty. It will then evaluate every part `1`, `2`, then `1001` and since that is the tail expression that is the result of the evaluation. You can have as many consequences in each `cond` term, but all before the tail is just for effect.

You could add one extra pair of parentheses and it would work as you expected:

```
(define (abs x)
  (cond ((< x 0) x)
        ((= x 0) 0)
        ((+ 1 2 1001))))
```

Here it has no addictional consequences and the truthy result of the predicate is the result for `(abs 1)`. One would want the code to be as clear as possible so using `else` here is a much better option:

```
(define (abs x)
  (cond ((< x 0) x)
        ((= x 0) 0)
        (else (+ 1 2 1001))))
```

This helps with another problem as well. While a number is always thruthy if you do the predicate trick with something that may be `#f` the result is undefined in the spec. Thus:

```
  (cond ((other-proc x)))
  ; ==> ??
```

If the call to `other-proc` is truthy the result is that, if it is `#f` you get the result chosen by the implementers. These are almost always truthy values with crazy visualizations like `#<undefined>` but can be anything like `"BaNaNa"` or even `#f`. Thus it is wise to have an `else` term so that you and not some other developer gets to choose the outcome :-)